# Retrieve deleted pull request on github?

Tags: github, branch, pull-request, repo

I'm overseeing a small open source project and we use github.
A contributor sent us a PR with some good work we really want to have, and would struggle to replicate, including some files that aren't code

Direct link if it's helpful: https://github.com/DS-13-Dev-Team/DS13/pull/1994

Unfortunately, this contributor got into a fight with another team member, things got out of hand, and he left the project, before I got around to reviewing and merging this work. He deleted his repo and closed the PR too.

We would still like to merge this contribution. He's given me verbal permission to do so, but has no interest in active participation anymore. Getting the files from him directly seems unlikely.

Is there any way for us to restore and reopen this pull request?

Comment: But from what I see all commits in this PR are still accessible?

Comment: All the commits emerge from "unknown repository" now though

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way for us to restore and reopen this pull request?

You can at least [check out hos PR branch locally](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/reviewing-changes-in-pull-requests/checking-out-pull-requests-locally)

```
git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME
git switch BRANCHNAME
```

(Rename `BRANCHNAME` with a local branch name which makes sense in your case)

From there you can:

- push `BRANCHNAME` to your repository
- open a new PR from there.

Comment: The branchname doesn't show, it says the PR comes from Unknown repository now. I don't think carrying out this command is possible, am i wrong?

Comment: @Nanako I meant: replace `BRANCHNAME` by any name you want: this is just to get a local branch which will reflect `pull/1994/head`

Comment: @Nanako That way, you will have a new PR from your repository, to your repository, where you can conduct review and discussion.

Comment: @Nanako Did it work?

Comment: i'm not having much luck, primarily because i'm not familiar with using git bash, i generally use smartgit for these things.

Plus our team works on their own forks, and makes PRs targeting the upstream repo. Origin points to my own fork, and this guy's PR branch was on his fork

will this make it harder?

Comment: @Nanako Once you have pushed that fetched PR branch, you will be able to open a new PR, based on this old one.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean
I can't fetch it, the repo it was in is entirely gone. It was this contributor's fork of our repo

Comment: @Nan The pr branch already exist in your repository: fetch that one.

Comment: I don't think it does, this is all of our branches
https://github.com/DS-13-Dev-Team/DS13/branches/all

The PR branch existed on this person's own repository which is a fork of ours, people don't push branches directly to the repo

Comment: @Nanako OK, but still, did you *try* `git fetch origin pull/113/head:DS113bis`? Then `git switch DS133bis`, and `git  push -u origin DS113bis`, and then try to open a PR from that new branch `DS113bis`?